# Error in Cypher curl REST with multiple start points

Tags: json, rest, curl, neo4j, cypher

I am getting the following error when i am trying to pass a cypher query via REST using curl command. My problem is something silly specific to curl command, which i am not able to figure out.

On this query (very simple version of my query):

```
curl -X POST http://myhostname02:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{ "query": "start ca=node:ca('NUM_CA:(\"000999\", \"000177\")') return ca.NME_CA", "params": {} }'
```

**Error: (Console Dump)**

```
[user@myhostname02 neo4j]$ curl -X POST http://myhostname02:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{ "query": "start ca=node:ca('NUM_FA:(\"000999\", \"000177\")') return ca.NME_CA", "params": {} }'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

But, same JSON i am successfully able to run from http web console and as cypher.
I have done many queries but with a single start point, i am not sure what went wrong with this one. The following one successfully executes (with single start point):

```
curl -X POST http://myhostname02:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: applicatio/json" --data-binary '{ "query": "start ca=node:ca(NUM_CA=\"000999\") return ca.NME_CA", "params": {} }'
```

Please help me understand this!

Edited- to add console dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no end quote on the query.

Update (now that the end quote is fixed):
It still has to do with quotes. You have single quotes in the middle around the lucene query, and surrounding the whole message. If you put it in a file, it works. Try this:

```
 $ cat test.json
 { "query": "start ca=node:ca('NUM_CA:(\"000999\", \"000177\")') return ca.NME_CA", "params": {} }
 $ curl -X POST -d @test.json http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/CypherPlugin/graphdb/execute_query -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Sorry for that, actually i have used an end quote in my query, check the console dump(added). I missed it while posting it here. If end quote would be missing, usually neo4j gives an error like  "exception" : "MediaTypeNotSupportedException".